# Jquery: function keeps executing on element after its class has been removed

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I am trying to add rows to a table after blurring the very last input. It is working pretty well, but it is adding a new row every single time I blur any input. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
$(function() {
$('#addNew').click(function() {

$('input').removeClass('last');

$('#all_items tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="item_'+i+'" id="items_'+i+'" class="last field" /></td><td>and other input fields</td></tr>');

$.ajax({
    url: "js/autocomplete.php?count="+i,
    success: function(newhtml){
        newhtml += "<";
        newhtml += "/script>";
        $("head").append(newhtml);
    }
});

i++;
});

//on blur click on addNew
$('.last').blur(function() {
$('#addNew').trigger('click');
});

});
</script>
```

autocomplete.php is like:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    //this section autocompletes the rows. Disregard for this question
    var data = [-data retrieved by a function, working well!-];
     $( "#items_'.$count.'" ).catcomplete({ delay: 0, source: data,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#price_'.$count.'").val(ui.item.price);
            $("#category_'.$count.'").val(ui.item.category);
        }
         });
  });

$(".last").blur(function() { 
  $("#addNew").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

and the html:

```
<span id="addNew">Add Item</span>

<table id="all_items">
<tr id="header"><th>Item</th><th>Note</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th></tr>
<tr id="first"><td><input type="text" name="item_0" id="items_0" class="last text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item_note_0" id="item_note_0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_0" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price_0" id="price_0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="category_0" id="category_0" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

By inspecting elements (Chrome) I can see the class 'last' is removed, but those fields still add a row/input at the end of the table when I blur them. What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid them keeping that behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event is attached with elements having class `last` are never removed when you remove `class` from the element. You have to `unbind` the event along with removing class from the element. You can use [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove the event from elements.

```
$('.last').unbind();
```

Comment: right on the coin!!! $('.last').unbind(); did the trick. THANK YOU very much, boss.

Comment: well... $('.last').unbind(); also avoids autocomplete to work. I changed to $('.last').unbind('blur'); to make the whole thing to work as expected.